# In Algolia, how do I set it to return search results even if not all of the keywords are found on data ?

Tags: algolia

By default if I search say   'fast red car' in Algolia, it will return results that has all 'fast red car' words on it. I want results to include data even if it has only has 'red', 'car' or 'fast' on it. Anybody knows how to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `removeWordsIfNoResults` Algolia setting to `allOptional`. Then all query words will be considered as optional and results will be returned even when some of the words are missing.

Depending on your use case I'd recommend you to consider not using `allOptional` but one of other options `lastWords` or `firstWords` as it might result in better relevance.

Documentation of `removeWordsIfNoResults` option: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/parameters#removewordsifnoresults